# Watch position in real time with Cordova BackgroundGeolocation Plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm working with Ionic and Cordova plugins. I had an app which worked with Cordova Background-mode and Geolocation plugins:

```
this.backgroundMode.enable();

this.backgroundMode.on("activate").subscribe(() => {
    this.backgroundMode.disableWebViewOptimizations(); // For GPS tracking at background
});

let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition({enableHighAccuracy: true});
watch.subscribe((resp) => {
    // Use resp.latitude and resp.longitude
});
```

Until I realised that exists [BackgroundGeolocation plugin](https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation) which, in many users' opinion is much better and faster than using both plugins.

My problem is that **I don't know how to replicate my old code with this plugin**, I tried with:

```
const config: BackgroundGeolocationConfig = {
    desiredAccuracy: 0, // Best accuracy possible
    stationaryRadius: 0,
    distanceFilter: 0
};

this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config).subscribe((location: BackgroundGeolocationResponse) => {
    // Use location.latitude and location.longitude,
});
```

But this solution is not as "Real time" as the first one.

Thanks in advance and sorry about my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of searching and trying with it, I found that we should use Geolocation after BackgroundGeolocation. It works exactly as expected.

```
 const config: BackgroundGeolocationConfig = {
  desiredAccuracy: 1,
  stationaryRadius: 20,
  distanceFilter: 10,
  debug: true, //  enable this hear sounds for background-geolocation life-cycle.
  stopOnTerminate: false, // enable this to clear background location settings when the app terminates
  fastestInterval: 4000,
  interval: 10000
};

this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config)
  .then(() => {

    this.backgroundGeolocation.on(BackgroundGeolocationEvents.location).subscribe((location: BackgroundGeolocationResponse) => {
      console.log(location);
      this.http.post('http://riyadkhalifeh.com/insert.php', { log: location.latitude, lat: location.longitude }, {})
        .then(data => {

          console.log(data.status);
          console.log(data.data); // data received by server
          console.log(data.headers);

        })
        .catch(error => {

          console.log(error);
          console.log(error); // error message as string
          console.log(error);

        });
    });

  });

// start recording location
this.backgroundGeolocation.start();

//////////////
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
  this.http.post(url, { lat: resp.coords.latitude, long: resp.coords.longitude }, {})
    .then(data => {

      console.log(data.status);
      console.log(data.data); // data received by server
      console.log(data.headers);

    })
    .catch(error => {

      console.log(error);
      console.log(error); // error message as string
      console.log(error);

    });
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log('Error getting location', error);
});

let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition();
watch.subscribe((data) => {

  this.http.post(url, { lat: data.coords.latitude, long: data.coords.longitude }, {})
    .then(data => {

      console.log(data.status);
      console.log(data.data); // data received by server
      console.log(data.headers);

    })
    .catch(error => {

      console.log(error);
      console.log(error); // error message as string
      console.log(error);

    });
});
```

Good luck for everybody

Answer (score 0):

That should work, and if it is in real time but `.configure` is an observable and only listen when the coordinates change.

Comment: I walk around all the institution and it didn't send changes :S

Comment: have you tried modifying the values ​​of stationaryRadius and     distanceFilter??

Comment: Unfortunatelly, yes. I tried with values 1, 5 and 10. It had very "random" behaviour, sometimes it entered 5 consecutive times and others just did nothing